# Is there a way to debug Facebook Instant Articles?

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-instant-articles

As the title says, is there any way to debug (view elements, CSS, console, etc) a Facebook Instant Article? I need to verify if a CSS affects on of my elements.

I am just looking for a tool to debug or troubleshoot FB Instant Articles.

Answer (score 1):

You may install Pages Manager app for Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.pages.app&hl=en

After install and Login to the App you need to find a section Instant Articles, where you can see articles from your page under development and productions.

Hopefully it will be helpful for your testing before to publish and live them.